# Admob implementation and compliance

Tags: ios, swift, admob, gdprconsentform

Hi i'm currently implementing Admob into my iOS app. The code works fine and test ads are showing, but i have a few questions regarding GDPR and user consent that i couldn't find the answers too.

1. If a user don't give permission to the AppTrackingTransparency do i have to notify Admob in any way? My guess is no. Would think Apple wouldn't hand out the IDFA if the user deny it.
2. I use admobs UserMessagingPlatform to present a consent form. Is the user answer saved somewhere or do i need to save this?
3. Using the form mentioned above. Do i need to do anything if the user don't consent, or will admob see that consent is not given and not serve personalised ads?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the documentation say? So isn’t the place to ask about compliance. Nobody can advise on your specific setup.

Answer (score -1):

1. If a user don't give permission to the AppTrackingTransparency do i have to notify Admob in any way? My guess is no. Would think Apple wouldn't hand out the IDFA if the user deny it.

-> You don't need to notify admob explicitly. requestTrackingAuthorization method will take care of that for you. However do implement Delay app measurement for admob. https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#delay_app_measurement_optional

2. I use admobs UserMessagingPlatform to present a consent form. Is the user answer saved somewhere or do i need to save this?

-> UMPConsentStatus returns 4 values indicating consent status. You don't need to save them explicitly but can be saved for app usage https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#present_the_form_if_required

```
UMPConsentStatusUnknown: Unknown consent status.
UMPConsentStatusRequired: User consent required but not yet obtained.
UMPConsentStatusNotRequired: User consent not required. For example, the user is not in the EEA or UK.
UMPConsentStatusObtained: User consent obtained. Personalization not defined.
```

3. Using the form mentioned above. Do i need to do anything if the user don't consent, or will admob see that consent is not given and not serve personalised ads?

->
By default, the Google Mobile Ads SDK initializes app measurement and begins sending user-level event data to Google immediately when the app starts. This initialization behavior ensures you can enable AdMob user metrics without making additional code changes.

However, if your app requires user consent before these events can be sent, you can delay app measurement until you explicitly initialize the Mobile Ads SDK or load an ad.

To delay app measurement, add the GADDelayAppMeasurementInit key with a boolean value of YES to your app’s Info.plist. You can make this change programmatically:
GADDelayAppMeasurementInit

https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#delay_app_measurement_optional

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful! Just to be clear, if i implement GADDelayAppMeasurementInit admob will delay sending metrics and if the user don't give permission, admob will only serve non personalised ads right?

Comment: no that is incorrect... by default google will serve personalized ad to end user. Its developer responsibility to make sure consent is taken before implementing any advertisements. Implement GADDelayAppmeasurement and then delay admob implementation till user accepts or declines form. By default personalized ads are shown . ref - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7676680#npa

Comment: Ok, so i should add 'GADDelayAppMeasurementInit' to the plist. Then wait for the user to consent before i call 'GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)' or if the user dont consent i should add this https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#forward-consent and then call 'GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)'

Comment: @swiftdev4585 - sound's like good plan!